# What is the difference between calling task-returning method directly and warping the task-returning method with Task.Run?

Tags: .net, async-await

I know that Task.Run will get a thread from threadpool to run that method, beside that why in the following code it needs to warp the task-returning method with Task.Run.

I am referring to the https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md

```
GOOD Task-returning methods are better since unhandled exceptions trigger the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException.

public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("/start")]
    public IActionResult Post()
    {
     *//this line, why wrap it in Task.Run
        Task.Run(BackgroundOperationAsync);*
        return Accepted();
    }
    
    public async Task BackgroundOperationAsync()
    {
        var result = await CallDependencyAsync();
        DoSomething(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Main difference: you're wasting a thread and causing thread switches for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason is to make sure the entire method runs on a separate thread. If you just called it directly, the part before the first `await` would run on the current thread.

In this particular example there is no code before the first await, but I think the idea is there *could* be.

Comment: I think that this is the reason

Answer (score 1):

> beside that why in the following code it needs to warp the task-returning method with Task.Run.

There isn't a good reason. Since this is ASP.NET Core, the code is roughly equivalent to

```
_ = BackgroundOperationAsync();
```

The primary point that the example is trying to make is to avoid `async void` and to use `async Task` instead (for `BackgroundOperationAsync`). However, the specific example I think is problematic because doing fire-and-forget on ASP.NET Core *at all* is not what I would ever call a "GOOD" solution; while `async Task` is marginally better than `async void`, neither are "good" solutions.